# Android book, like google play ebook reader

Tags: android, textview

I want to create a book that have options like ebook readers but with a fixed text.
I tried to use textview but I don't know how to manage text to split it into pages.
Beside I like to have a page curl effect like google play books has.

Please give me some example if you can or the logic it should to be.
Thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEQW9.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Book you actually need a book i.e. a PDF not in a Text View. There is a **[library that](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library)** you can use for PDF Viewing.